# Not able to get the value from the `directive` scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the `value` from `ng-repeat` `directive`, but only i am consoled by `$index`, the `value` consoles as `undefiend`.

what is wrong here?

my code :

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="main">
     <h1>{{index}}</h1>

     <new-array index='$index' ng-repeat="value in values">{{value}}</new-array>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('main', function ($scope) {

  $scope.values = [{"name":"one", "num" : 1}, {"name":"two", "num" : 2}, {"name":"three", "num" : 3}]

  $scope.index = 0;

  $scope.update = function (num) {
    $scope.index = num;
  }

});

myApp.directive("newArray", function () {

  return {

    scope : {
      value : "=",
      index : "="
    },

    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

      console.log(scope.value, scope.index)
      //reusult as "undefined" 1

    }

  }

})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JOp3ffzQQ2HITImoYrAW?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<new-array index='$index' ng-repeat="value in values">{{value}}</new-array>
```

should be

```
<new-array index='$index' value='value' ng-repeat="value in values">{{value}}</new-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your directive you are setting the scope to

```
  scope : {
      value : "=",
      index : "="
    }
```

This way you are creating an isolate scope that does not inherit from the parent scope. So you have to pass the value into the directive as "simoco" explained.